# Is there a pythonic way to merge a dataframe on the datetime with datapairs with an irregular datetimestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have several dataseries, where every datapoint is saved with a timestamp with an accuracy of [ms]. I want to merge these series to be on one timeline, all timestamps should be sampled with an accuracy of [s] And in the end there should be one pd where the first column is the datetime with all different timestamps from the series .All the other columns are merged on that datetime.

My code is working, but fails on large data because of memory.

Data looks like this:

```
a_data; a_Timestamp; b_data; b_Timestamp; c_data ; c_Timestamp
1; 2019-07-24 12:00:00.123; 2 ; 2019-07-24 12:00:00.234; 3 ; 2019-07-24 12:00:00.345;
2; 2019-07-24 12:00:03.123; 3 ; 2019-07-24 12:00:02.234; 4 ; 2019-07-24 12:00:03.645;
```

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def prepareData(df):
    dfm = None
    df = df.dropna(axis='columns',how='all')
    df = df.sort_index()  

    for col in df:
        dt = None
        if not "Timestamp" in col:
            series = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime' : pd.to_datetime(df[col + '_Timestamp']).astype('datetime64[s]'),col : df[col]})
            if mergedFrame is not None:
                dfm = dfm.merge(series, on='DateTime', how ='outer').sort_values('DateTime')           
            else:
                dfm = series    
        dfm = dfm.loc[~dfm.DateTime.duplicated(keep='first')]
    dfm = dfm.sort_index()
    dfm = dfm.fillna(method='ffill')
    dfm = dfm.fillna(method='bfill')
    dfm = dfm.fillna(0)
    return dfm.reset_index()       

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep = ";", na_values="n/a" ,low_memory=False)
prepareData(df).to_csv( 'file_sampled.csv', sep = ';')
```

result should be

```
DateTime; a_data; b_data ; c_data
2019-07-24 12:00:00; 1;2;3
2019-07-24 12:00:02; 1;3;3
2019-07-24 12:00:03; 2;3;3 
2019-07-24 12:00:04; 2;3;4
```

I got this result, but the memory it takes is too much for my pc. I guess there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we select every data and every timestamp column and put them side by side:

```
x = pd.concat([pd.melt(df.iloc[:,::2], value_name='data'), pd.melt(df.iloc[:,1::2], value_name='DateTime').iloc[:,-1]], axis=1)
```

Convert date time strings do DateTime, round to full seconds and set as index:

```
x['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(x.DateTime).dt.round('s')
x = x.set_index('DateTime')
```

Finally we pivot the data:

```
x.pivot(columns='variable', values='data')
```

Result:

```
variable             a_data  b_data  c_data
DateTime                                   
2019-07-24 12:00:00     1.0     2.0     3.0
2019-07-24 12:00:02     NaN     3.0     NaN
2019-07-24 12:00:03     2.0     NaN     NaN
2019-07-24 12:00:04     NaN     NaN     4.0
```

Comment: That looks way more pythonic and i guess it works. But i still get the memory error :( Btw i got 48GB and the .csv is 520 mb maybe i will need to do the reordering in a few more steps, to only do it on 50 rows each time for example. The difficulty here is that not every column is recorded in the same cycle. For some Data there are 5 datapoints within 5 seconds for others its just 1 within 5 seconds. This leads to a difference length of rows for every column.

Comment: What if you do it by chunks? What is the memory usage of your entire data frame after you read it from the csv (last row of `df.info()`)?

Comment: 606 columns, dtypes: float64(343), object(264), memory usage: 1.9+ GB. With chunks you mean smth like  
    for i in range(0, len(l), 50):
        yield l[i:i + n]

Comment: It seems like i was too fast with my running your code. Memory was not cleared on my last try, so it was already blocked before. code is now in progress, at the moment without an error.

Comment: inserting `x['variable'] = x.variable.astype('category')` after my first line `x = pd.concat(...` will also reduce memory consumption (provided you managed to calculate x of course)

Comment: with chunks I meat processing not the whole csv in one run but specify the `chunksize` parameter and process it then chunk by chunk. Concatenate the resulting `file_sampled.csv` in the file system is easiest when you write the header in the first csv file only.

Comment: Hi Stef, yes i did. But there still is a fault in the logic, if i round the date after the merge i can not set it as index because there are some duplicate dates. I will need to get them all on the same datetime and set them afterwards to the index Datetime. If i just delete the first, like i did previously i lose all the other data.

Comment: If there are duplicate entries in the resulting table, you'll need to apply an aggregation function on the values (e.g. take the average value: `x.pivot_table(columns='variable',index=x.index , values='data')`) instead of `x.pivot(columns='variable', values='data')`.

Comment: The problem is somehow different, if you look at the two lines i posted in the question. It is like dt of a-data and b_data only differ on ms, if you round them after merging you get two lines with the same dt, but different values. I have to round the dt of each row before merging.

Comment: you can do it before merging by `for c in df.columns[1::2]:` with `df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c]).dt.round('s')`, but as far as I understand this won't change anything as the proble arises only later when trying to pivot the data.